# How to put geom_text in ggplot2 above all layers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, overlap

When I add text with `geom_text`, this text is overlapped by layers generated by other geoms. The order of drawing is defined by the order of the data, but that doesn't help when the text belongs to the data drawn by the same geom: some lines from different groups necessarily overlap each other's text. That is, some text is always blocked by graphics from another group.

How can I put `label` of `geom_text` above everything else?

Comment: Please edit to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Did you try adding `geom_text` after all other geoms?

Comment: Have you looked at the [**help texts for `geom_text`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html)? The influence of order of `geom`s is evident when you look at the examples with coloured text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which you add the geom's determines the order in the plot:

```
ggplot() + geom_line() + geom_text()
```

puts the `geom_text` above the `geom_line`.